# C++ tbb_debug.dll missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, opencv, tbb

I'm new with openCV and I tried followed some tutorials. Everything worked fine until I included: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp and used the filter2D function. I got the following error when I start my program:

"The program can't start because tbb_debug.dll is missing from your computer."

On the internet I have found that this error has something to do with 32 and 64 bit versions of dlls.

I'm using the 64bit version of windows and created a 32bit console application in VS2010 and the application uses the 32 bit version of the openCV dll's.
When I start the program "dependency walker", I can see that my program uses the 64bit version of all system dll's (in C:\windows\system32....). Only the dll's of opencv are 32bit.

screenshot of depenency walker:

[image]
Thanks

Comment: You must use the 32-bit version of dependency walker to analyze 32-bit programs (you can have both versions of dependency walker installed).

Answer (score 27):

I assume that you are using pre-compiled OpenCV 2.3 binaries. The package, for some reason, ships with tbb dlls but not the debug ones (i.e., say with tbb.dll, but not tbb_debug.dll). You need to get that from Intel [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/file.php?fid=77) or as part of an Intel software [suite](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-sdp-home/) (if you want to buy/try). Once you get this, all you need to do is put the dlls in path where your program's executable can find it. Easiest way is to copy all tbb*_debug.dll to the OpenCV bin folder ..../build/common/tbb/intel64/vc10/

UPDATE [May '12]: OpenCV 2.4 is out now, and it does ship with all the requisite dlls!

Comment: I am using 2.4.0 only... I had the same problem

Answer (score 4):

For all of You who want to try the **simplest solution** (it is **the only solution** that worked for me) is:

1. right click on Your project in Visual Studio
2. select "Properties"
3. under the Intel performance libraries options
4. select "YES" for "Use TBB"

As explained in [this video starting from 2:55](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7RTw1VM6Js&t=02m55s)

Good luck People! :)

====
EDIT - updated the video link (first and the last time)

Comment: Can you please update the link to the video, it`s broken?

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan the video was put just as additional info. Since the procedure is pretty straightforward, I will not be updating the link again.

Answer (score 3):

If you need Intel TBB dll's you can get that from

www.threadingbuildingblocks.org - > Go to the download area.