# tbb_debug.dll Missing - MSER Sample OpenCV 2.3.1

Tags: dll, opencv, tbb

I am trying to use the MSER sample found in the **samples** directory of OpenCV 2.3.1.
At the moment the DLL missing error keeps popping up. This is the first time I am testing the MSER code and doubt that there is any dependency on TBB (Thread Building Block Routines).

Can I disable this dependency? Has anyone encountered this problem? I downloaded the OpenCV2.3.1 super pack today. And I am stuck on the very first sample I am testing.

Thanks for the guidance.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ tbb_debug.dll missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293160/c-tbb-debug-dll-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known "feature" of OpenCV 2.3.1 Windows package. The dll is really missing and you need to find it somewhere. The recent 2.4.0 beta has this dll.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate. Please confirm.

Comment: That topic is about OpenCV 2.3.0. It is the only difference.